# MVC 3 Code first First with built-in membership authentication

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, code-first

I would like to use code first EF 4.1 to build my application. I'm using MVC 3. I would simultaneously like to use Membership authentication. The problem I see mainly is how do I do a foreign key to the membership users table that was generated by the tool, to the model i'm creating via code.

for example:

dbo.aspnet_Users which has a guid as it's PK
I want to create a user in MY user table (dbo.Users) with the same GUID as my PK.

Is there a way to form that association without it just being implied by the matching data?

Comment: If I understand right you problem, I had something like that and in my case I created a table to hold extra information from my users and attached the tool generated table id as FK.

I tried to change the membership table but EF didnt like it much.

Comment: It's exactly like that. Trying to figure out how to do this in code first

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quiete sure what you are trying to achieve. If you want to associate custom data to a user, you could use the profile.
Is there a special reason why you like to sort of "douplicate" some user information?

Comment: Because the profiles table would just make things convoluted. I would rather have a sister table that stored meaningful information about the user.

Comment: Okay then you have to implement your own MembershipUser along with a MempershipProvider (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366730.aspx)